# How to render two or more templates?

Tags: django-templates

I have two templates to render in my django project:
This is template 'b.html'

```
<html>
<body>
{% include 'a.html' %}
     {{ userName}}
</body>
</html>
```

and it's the 'a.html':

```
     {{ another_name}}
```

And I'm finishing tasks and return userName to 'b.html' and another_name to 'a.html',what should I do?Should use **render_to_response**?Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the doc for the `include` tag : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include

And you can use `render_to_response()` to render your template :

```
return render_to_response('b.html', {
     'userName': 'a',
     'another_name': 'b'
}
```